# How to upload images to Imgur using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload, imgur

Is there any way I can upload images to Imgur using Laravel.

I am currently using

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', [
    'headers' => [
        'authorization' => 'Client-ID ' . 'app_id',
        'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ],
    'form_params' => [
        'image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('thumbnail')))
    ],
]);
return response()->json(json_decode(($response->getBody()->getContents())));
```

My blade file is

```
<tr>
    <td>Thumbnail</td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I keep on getting `Call to a member function path() on null`

What I want to do is to get a file upload, upload it to Imgur and get the URL back to insert it into my database.

Comment: Did you try to use some `dump`s in your code? What if you dump `$request->file('thumbnail')`?

Comment: Thanks for that. I just checked my Blade File. I was using 'file' instead of 'thumbnail' in the request. Now how would I get the URL out of the response?

Comment: What's the response of the Guzzle request? Could you try `dump(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true));`

Comment: Another error. `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `POST https://api.imgur.com/3/image` resulted in a `403 Permission Denied` response: {"data":{"error":"Malformed auth header","request":"\/3\/image","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":403}`

I am using authentication using headers.

Comment: I have sorted the problem the headers were missplaced

Comment: So there is something wrong with the authorization header. From what I understand is that they use the Oauth2 flow and you need an access token. The `Client-ID` part in the `Authorization` header is only used to get the access token. Once you’ve got that, you need to use `Bearer some-token` as value for the same header. Check their website: https://api.imgur.com/#authentication

Comment: So it’s working now?

Comment: It is working but I cannot seem to find a way to extract the link from the JSON. Dumping it shows the link but when I try to extract the specific line it doesn't work. Here is the dump. I am trying to extract the link only. https://hastebin.com/joguritewu.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$file = $request->file('file');
        $file_path = $file->getPathName();
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', [
            'headers' => [
                    'authorization' => 'Client-ID ' . 'your-client-id-here',
                    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ],
            'form_params' => [
                    'image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('file')->path($file_path)))
                ],
            ]);
        $data['file'] = data_get(response()->json(json_decode(($response->getBody()->getContents())))->getData(), 'data.link');
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Laravel 9 and above answer,

```
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $file_path = $file->getPathName();
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'authorization' => 'Client-ID ' . 'your-client-id-here',
            'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ])->send('POST', 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', [
            'form_params' => [
                    'image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('file')->path($file_path)))
                ],
            ]);
        $data['file'] = data_get(response()->json(json_decode(($response->getBody()->getContents())))->getData(), 'data.link');
```

do not use http facade `post()` method in sending form to imgur, it will  serialize the form data and server will get 400 bad method response.